# Python - Fitting surface to discrete data points

Tags: python, numpy, regression, surface

I need to compute a best (or good) fit to n-dimensional data (n = number of independent variables) that has one dependent variable. There is no analytical function but just a set of data points.

For an n=2 example with 3 values for each independent variable, I have the code:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1., 2., 3.]) 
x2 = np.array([10.0, 11.0, 12.0] )
xdata = []
xdata.append(x1)
xdata.append(x2)

z = np.array([[4.0, 2.0, 4.0], [11.0, 20.0, 11.0], [0.5, 0.4, 0.5]])
```

z is a 2D array with 9 values (3 x 3 values)

For n=3, I have data that looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
x2 = np.array([10.0, 11.0, 12.0])
x3 = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
xdata = []
xdata.append(x1)
xdata.append(x2)
xdata.append(x3)

z = np.array([[[4.0, 2.0, 4.0], [11.0, 20.0, 11.0], [0.5, 0.4, 0.5]],
              [[8.3, 8.1, 9.0], [4.2, 0.1, 0.2], [10.1, 4.5, 1.2]],
              [[7.2, 7.21, 7.22], [0.8, 1.2, 0.9],[ 4.1, 0.3, 3.1]]] )
```

z is a 3 dimensional array with 27 values (3 x 3 x 3 values).

I'd like to write Python code to find a surface, either using a polynomial of some order or a multi-dimensional regression, that is as close as possible to the data.

Then I would like to be able to "interrogate" the function for arbitrary values of the independent variables but within the upper and lower bounds.

I've tried scipy.optimize.curve_fit and the regression function in scikit learn but I'm having trouble understanding how to use these functions with my data in the previous form.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that x1 and x2 are the 'ticks' of the grid, that is `f(x1[i], x2[j]) = z[i,j]`; is that correct?

Comment: Those are the list of data points in the "x1" direction and the "x2" direction respectively. Think of it as the x and y variables.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is to "interrogate" the function inside of your domain (i. e. interpolate), I'd suggest looking at `scipy.interpolate`.

A multilinear interpolation would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

z = np.array([[4.0 , 2.0 , 4.0 ], 
              [11.0, 20.0, 11.0],
              [0.5 , 0.4 , 0.5 ],
              [1.0 ,-5.0 , 0.5 ]])

x1 = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4]) 
x2 = np.array([10.0, 11.0, 12.0])

f = RegularGridInterpolator((x1, x2), z, bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)
def convenient_f(x1, x2):
    x = np.vstack((x1.ravel(), x2.ravel())).T
    z = f(x)
    return z.reshape(x1.shape)
```

And the you can call `convenient_f(x1, x2)` with your new points. For example, you can easily plot it:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2, indexing='ij')
x1_surface, x2_surface = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(1, 4, 20), np.linspace(10, 12, 20), indexing='ij')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(X1.ravel(), X2.ravel(), z.ravel(), "ok")
ax.plot_surface(x1_surface, x2_surface, convenient_f(x1_surface, x2_surface), alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Illustration of the multilinear interpolation]

Comment: Great! I'll give that a try.

Comment: This works very well. I'm glad you noticed the "interrogate" wording. Thanks a million!

Comment: BTW - I'm going to try to some multiple linear regression tests as an experiment. Again - really glad you helped out!